# REGEX percentage 2 decimal with + and minus value

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex to check percentage with 2 decimals up to 100

```
^-?(100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)
```

but is working only in `99.16` and not like `-99.16`

How to allow also minus percentage?

Comment: `(^-?(100([.]0{1,2})?)$)|(^-?[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]{1,2})?)`; please, notice `-?` in the second alternative of the expression

Comment: You can also use a [group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group): [`^-?(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d\d?(?:\.\d\d?)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pN3rT5/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just missed the ^-? in the second option

```
^-?(100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^-?\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)
```

Comment: a typo, doesn't matter actually, it works the same, i'll remove it

Comment: Thank you for fast reply

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* alternatives:

- special case of 100 precent
- standard case of 0..99 precent

*both* alternatives can have *minus sign* (`-`):

```
  (^-?(100([.]0{1,2})?)$)|(^-?[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$)
```

as a remark, you probably want `[0-9]` when matching *digits* not any character treated as digit `'\d'` which include, say, Persian digits `۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷`

Comment: @Xufox: Nice find! I should not have copied + pasted the *original regex*.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply

Comment: On your side note: is there a way to make `\d` *not* match Persian digits?

Comment: @LinusKleen, it is actually the opposite. By default in Java the character class `\d` will not match non-ASCII digits (such as `۱`; U+06F1) unless you use the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS): `"\u06F1".matches("\\d") == false`, `"\u06F1".matches("(?U)\\d") == true`